# Box2d trampoline, synchronize with sprite animation

Tags: java, box2d

I am creating 2d game, I decided to implement trampoline in my game (object which will throw player up in the air after jumping on it) At beginning I simply was setting some linear velocity to the player after players feet contact with trampoline.. but since its bit ugly, I decided to use proper art with animation, to describe this animation, take a look at this image (example only!)

[image]

I thought to use kinematic body for the trampoline, after contact between player and it, trampoline body would be moved down and than up throwing player up. Lets say I have sprite sheet with 4 states of the trampoline (in 2d)

1) normal state (trampoline in standard state)
2) squeezed in 30%
3) squeezed in 60%
4) squeezed in 100%

And now my question is, how to handle this issue, to change sprite animation tile, accoring to the body state. Also is there different better option to support it than the one which I mentioned (kinematic body for trampoline)? Thanks.

Comment: Using a kinematic body for this seems like a reasonable idea. Since you will be controlling the movement of the kinematic body, you will know how high it currently is, so why not just draw the closest sprite to the current height of the trampoline?

Comment: Thanks for answer, well I have been thinking about this, and I came to conclusion that kinematic body might be bad idea. Why? Because, lets think about following scenario: Players jumps on trampoline, trampoline body (Kinematic) has to strongly go  down (Y axis) with quite big power, to make it look realistic and elastic, but players body will keep falling with normal gravity, which means it might look strange. With this way, I guess we could add same force to players body, equals to the force applied to the trampoline body, so they will go down with same speed, still just thinking.

Comment: About controlling movement, I will probably use update handler to check current trampoline "squeeze state" by checking Y value on every update.

Comment: It all depends on how you want the trampoline to feel. Should it always spring the player up to a fixed height, can the player bounce on it repeatedly to get higher, etc. I don't think anyone can give a good answer on how you should implement it without knowing more details like that. Another way you could perhaps do it is to just have a sensor there to detect that the player is on the trampoline area, and control the movement directly by applying forces or impulses to the player body itself.

Comment: What I exactly want to achieve is simpler goal, as you mentioned - spring the player up to a fixed height. Thank you.